# Push to docker registry is denied

Tags: docker, gitlab

Let me start off admitting that this is a crosspost from the gitlab forum here: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/push-to-docker-registry-is-denied/35018. I didn't get any response there, so I hope I am luckier here.

When I try to log into my gitlab’s docker registry, it fails. Same for the push. I have gitlab running in a docker container. The registry is bound to port 5005.

Trying to log in via gitlab.myHostname.com:5005 fails. The same with :443 and :80. Trying to log in via gitlab.myHostname.com succeeds. Yet pushing fails always.

When I am not pushing to port 5005, every connection goes through a separate nginx, that is distinct from the nginx that runs in the gitlab docker container.

Here is my gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 31422
registry_external_url 'https://gitlab.myDomain.com'
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "https://gitlab.myDomain.com:5005"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
nginx['client_max_body_size'] = '4G'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
nginx['listen_port'] = 443
nginx['listen_https'] = true
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/letsencrypt.pem"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/letsencrypt.key"
```

And here is my docker-compose for gitlab:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitlab:
    networks:
      default:
        aliases: 
          - gitlab.docker
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.8.0-ce.0'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.myDomain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.myDomain.com'
    ports:
      - '31422:22'
      - '5005:5005'
    volumes:
      - '/etc/gitlab:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/log/gitlab:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - '/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.myDomain.com/fullchain.pem:/etc/gitlab/ssl/letsencrypt.pem'
      - '/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.myDomain.com/privkey.pem:/etc/gitlab/ssl/letsencrypt.key'
    labels:
      - 'com.dnsdock.alias=gitlab.docker'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myDomain0
```

And finally, here is the error message I receive on push:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.myDomain.com:5005/v2/: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:5005: (EDIT: ip changed for privacy) connect: connection refused
The push refers to repository [gitlab.myDomain.com:5005/docker/sbt]
Get https://gitlab.myDomain.com:5005/v2/: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:5005: (EDIT: ip changed for privacy) connect: connection refused
```

Anyone any idea how to deal with it?

EDIT:
I purposefully changed my hostname for privacy. When you see `gitlab.myDomain.com`, that's actually a real domain. And if you find an IP `0.0.0.0`, then this is my public IP.

Comment: have you edited the log and replaced the actual domain with gitlab.mydomain.com, or is it like that in your config?

Comment: I edited that. I use my actual domain in reality. Should have pointed that out. Same for the IP address, but there I pointed it out.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from editing your question to still point it out. ;)

Comment: Try the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698748/connection-refused-on-pushing-a-docker-image): `docker run -d -p 5005:5005 --restart=always --name registry registry:2` to create the local registry.

Comment: That doesn't look like a solution. That creates a separate registry and doesn not fix my gitlab issue. Those images won't be visible via gitalb and I cannot use gitlab access token to access them.

Comment: Does [this document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab) relate to what you are doing, and have you followed all the steps?

Comment: Yes, that shows pretty much what I did, with the slight difference that I have gitlab also running in a container and that when I try to `docker login` it says denied.

Comment: You are trying to connect on your public IP... do you have port forwarding configured correctly, and if you're trying to connect from internally (i.e: beside the machine running gitlab), do you also have [hairpin NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) configured correctly? Can you confirm with something more basic (e.g: `netcat`)

Comment: Note also, that [docker will require secure connections for all registries by default](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/), so resolving this issue may just reveal the next issue (being no HTTPS).

Comment: A preferred solution might be to use a proxy like [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) that will also act as the TLS endpoint, handle certificates for you and has good integration with docker.